# Unable to upload files with long Name and long folder path using REST

Tags: rest

I am trying to upload files to Sharepoint 2013 using REST based services. 
The upload works fine if the name of the file is less than 109 characters and the folder path less than 123 characters.

I have files with larger names and bigger folder paths. Any clues how do I fix this?

Tina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am affraid, you will not bypass this limit. MSFT enfoce this limit from 2003. there is a limitation in URL length as 260 characters. Please check this article to understanding the

[URL path length restrictions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919564(v=office.15).aspx)

Even, if you able to upload a file with long name, but still it will not for the user, becuase when user trying to edit or open the doucment then SharePoint will throw the same error.

> "The URL for this file is too long for the application.  A temporary
>   copy of this file will be opened on 
>                  your computer.  You must save this copy as a new file"

[Unable to edit files uploaded to document library where url length is more than 260 characters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvagan/archive/2009/12/06/unable-to-edit-files-uploaded-to-document-library-where-url-length-is-more-than-260-characters.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Waqas. But somehow I am able to upload files using Soap and able to open them as well on Sharepoint

Comment: that is really strange, then I say you are good developer...you sure the total character is >260?

Comment: This is my path - [link]https://xxxxx52.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/DocumentLibrary/Global%20XXXX%20-%20Global%20Data%20Dissemination%20and%20Communications/ENGAGE-AF%20and%20xxxxxxx-VTE%20External%20Impressions/xxxxxxx-VTE%20External%20Impressions/Supporting%20Documents/ESC/SharePointUploadDocumentExample.properties

Comment: and you able to upload and then user able to view it in browser?

Comment: The path I mentioned is of a file uploaded using SOAP. And user is able to view it too.

Comment: I got the issue. Actually the file that I uploaded was a .properties file and Sharepoint didnt throw any errors. But I tried with an XLS with same name and it started throwing error. Thanks @Waqas.